# Picture converted to very low quality while sending MMS

Tags: mms

I've HTC Desire 2.3.3 . Recently I took one photo from stock camera app and clicked Menu -> Share -> MMS.

My picture was automatically converted to 7KB sized file. No doubt the picture lost all its quality.

I was wondering from where I can control this setting, so that I myself can define what size/quality should the MMS picture be. The only thing I found in MMS setting was maximum size of the message.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that its operator defined per all the discussion I have seen around this, and does seem to be correct when I consider that on TMobile in the UK I can send a picture file around 258KB - with 640*480 dimension JPEG without any issue - which is plenty big enough for phones.

I have checked to see if its working on a standard algorithm by using a much smaller picture file and size, however it still created a MMS around 200KB (around half the file size of the original picture), suggestion the algorithm is dynamic when it compresses the photo. Further suggesting it really is operator defined.

Comment: I've by default set 100KB as MMS size and my operator charges 1MMS per 100KB of file size. My main concern is the picture was compressed to 7KB, which looks way bad in quality.

Comment: I would suggest that is your issue then as the message would also header and text etc details. You might want to consider upping your file size - I know it will cost more. T-Mobile UK just seems to charge by message rather than size, Try seeing if you get a better size by bumping it up to 200KB - as T Mobile MMS seem to be double the cost of a std text.